# How to display data with percentage from database in pie chartjs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chart.js

I have a simple section in which I  am displaying data from the database, now I want to display those data with a percentage like this

[image]

here is my solution

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://meed.audiencevideo.com/admin/chats/stats.php",
  success:function(data)  {

    var session = [];
    var yes = [];
    var no =[]

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              session.push(data[i].sessions);
              yes.push(data[i].num_yes);
              no.push(data[i].num_no);
            }
            console.log("session ", + session);
            console.log("Yes " +  yes);
            console.log("No " +  no);
            var data = [{
              data: [session,yes, no],
              labels: ["session", "yes", "no"],
              backgroundColor: [
                  "#4b77a9",
                  "#5f255f",
                  "#d21243",
              ],
              borderColor: "#fff"
          }];

             var options = {
             tooltips: {
           enabled: false
      },
               plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                  formatter: (value, ctx) => {

                    let sum = 0;
                    let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                    dataArr.map(data => {
                        sum += data;
                    });
                    let percentage = (value*100 / sum).toFixed(2)+"%";
                    return percentage;


                  },
                  color: '#fff',
                       }
          }
      };

          var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart").getContext('2d');
           var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: {
              datasets: data
          },
                options: options
      });

    }
  });
```

The above solution displays me the following

[image]

displays 0.00% on all of the data, on console I have this

```
session  2714
Yes 390
No 111
```

When I pass data from database like this: `data: [session, yes, no]` i get `0.00%`

But if I pass data manually like this: `data: [2714, 390, 111]`, I get the data with a percentage on my pie chart.

What am I doing wrong in my code? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: You're missing an apostrophe here `type: 'pie,` – should read `type: 'pie',`

Comment: @Cue I have udpated my question check now

Comment: What's the value of `data[i].sessions` etc?

Comment: on console `session  2714`
`Yes 390`
`No 111`

Comment: @Cue please check it here on live demo  on console you will see those data https://meed.audiencevideo.com/admin/

Comment: @cue did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

To get everything into a percentage. You're gonna need to compute them.

Like so:

```
var total = session + total_yes + total_no;
session = (session / total) * 100;
total_yes = (total_yes / total) * 100;
total_no= (total_no / total) * 100;
```

Then in your chartdata, just use them:

```
var chartdata = {
      labels: ['session', 'yes', 'no'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'session',
          backgroundColor: ['#00a65a', '#FF00FF'],
          highlight: '#00c0ef',
          data: session
        },
        {
          label: 'yes',
          backgroundColor: ['#00a65a', '#FF00FF'],
          highlight: '#00c0ef',
          data:total_yes
        },
          {
          label: 'no',
          backgroundColor: ['#00a65a', '#FF00FF'],
          highlight: '#00c0ef',
          data:total_no
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you require to add more items just add it to the total variable them do the same to get the percentage and then add it to the chartdata. And so on.

Comment: I will check it and let you know